# Why are attributes not supported with the DataContractSerializer?

Tags: wcf, xsd, datacontractserializer, svcutil.exe

I create xsd's based upon client's documentation and all of the xsd's have attributes.  I have been using xsd.exe to generate the classes from the xsd's, but I read that attributes aren't supported for the DataContractSerializer.  Why not?  Does this mean that I can only have an soap+xml file with just elements?  This is not possible because I don't create the requests.  Is there a way to specify to svcutil to recognize attributes?

Comment: You just answered your own question.

Comment: @John, how?  I don't  understand why they would not be supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DataContractSerializer was created with a "code-first" philosophy in mind - it maps well to most programming languages (records, lists), and it doesn't handle all of XML constructs (such as attributes, or out-of-order elements, for example) for performance reasons.

WCF (svcutil) still supports using the XmlSerializer, which can handle AFAIK all of the XML constructs. svcutil should create a contract using the XmlSerializer if the DataContractSerializer can't handle it.

Comment: do you have an example of how to specify the svcutil to use XmlSerializer?

Comment: It depends on the option you're using svcutil. For example, when creating a proxy code, you can specify svcutil /serializer:XmlSerializer. svcutil /? will give you other usages.

Comment: Great. Thanks Carlos.  It is ironic that you answered this. I just came from your blog before I came here.